# Rust Unique Return Counts / Unique with Frequency

Tags: rust

What is the fastest way to to get the unique elements in a vector and their count? Similar to `numpy.unique(return_counts=True)`. The below becomes exceedingly slow as the array grows into the millions.

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main () {
    let kmers: Vec<u8> = vec![64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65];
    let nodes: HashMap<u8, usize> = kmers
        .iter()
        .unique()
        .map(|kmer| {
            let count = kmers.iter().filter(|x| x == &kmer).count();
            (kmer.to_owned(), count)
        })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", nodes)   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) for this. The linked docs have a similar example to what you need, here it is modified to fit your case:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main () {
    let kmers: Vec<u8> = vec![64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65];
    let mut nodes: HashMap<u8, usize> = HashMap::new();
    for n in kmers.iter() {
        nodes.entry(*n).and_modify(|count| *count += 1).or_insert(1);
    }

    println!("{:?}", nodes)   
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a271d28f1fc798723a69dccb8a90350)

If you want the output to be sorted, you can use a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer a one-liner, you can use itertools' [`counts()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.counts): (this uses the same code as in @PitaJ answer under the hood, with a little improvement):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main () {
    let kmers: Vec<u8> = vec![64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65];
    let nodes: HashMap<u8, usize> = kmers.iter().copied().counts();
    println!("{:?}", nodes)   
}
```